# «То» или «те»? Когда и как использовать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

***То*** были не мои идеи. ***Те*** были не мои идеи.
***То*** были мои дети. ***Те*** были мои дети.

Может кто объяснить, как правильно и почему? Может, есть контрольный вопрос или правило?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что объясню почему, но выскажу свои соображения. В первом случае с *"то"* вы указываете на идеи/детей. Можно заменить на *"это".* То, что в скобках, подразумевается:

> *То (что вы увидели перед собой) были не мои идеи.*

Этот вариант единственно правильный, на мой взгляд.

А вот *"те"* требует уточнения после себя. Предложения, оканчивающие обе строчки, не очень по-русски звучат, я бы их переписал так:

> *Те идеи не были моими.
>
>   Те дети были моими.*

Но всё равно первые предложения с *"то"* звучат гораздо органичнее.